# onAuthenticationSuccess is not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my application , I have three way to login the User 
form login,
autologin and 
remember me cookie.

I have to intercept the call after successful authentication of User, for that I am using **AuthenticationSuccessHandler** to intercept the call.

I am using spring security to authenticate the user. For form-based login, i have configured below code in spring-security.xml

```
form-login login-page="/login/formlogin" default-target-url="/login/user_login" 
                 authentication-failure-url="/login/loginfailed" 
authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

and

```
AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess();
```

is called just after the authentication is done successfully, but 
for autologin this method is never invoked.

For autologin user will be mailed a URL, clicking on the URL will authenticate the user, I am doing it programatically. In the URL I am putting the encrypted username (no password).
I am using the below lines of code to authenticate user when he clicks on a URL (autologin)

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But,

```
AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess()
```

is never called in this case.

Is there any other way to intercept the call on successfull authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse your existed auth success handler for both cases. RememberMe -  just configure it:

```
<remember-me authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
```

Autologin - inject the same auth success handler bean and call it after your code manually:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```