# After success login I can't to redirect to home page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

When I login after that I should to redirect to the home page. As I understand I redirect to  `/login` [POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj9Uq.png). And see blank page. How do I fix it?

I tried to write this one function but nothing happens.

```
.successForwardUrl("/")
.loginProcessingUrl("/")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
```

I create handler for success login

**SecurityConfig**

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/signup/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(SuccessLoginHandler())
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()

        http.addFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil = jwtUtil))
        http.addFilter(JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil = jwtUtil, userDetailService = adminDetailsServiceImpl))
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    }
```

**SuccessLoginHandler**

```
@Component
class SuccessLoginHandler : AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private val redirectStrategy: RedirectStrategy = DefaultRedirectStrategy()

    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, auth: Authentication?) {

        try {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/")
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            err.println(ex)
            throw RuntimeException()
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(mode: Model): String{
        return "index"
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun signUp(@RequestBody admin: AdminDTO): AdminDTO {
        admin.userRole = UserRole.ADMIN
        return adminService.create(admin)
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    fun login(): String {
        return "login"
    }
```

Comment: please paste your "/" request mapping method in your controller

Comment: @clevertension I have controller with this request mapping

Comment: if you visit http://your_host/ directly, is it still the blank page, or it will show the index page?

Comment: @clevertension it show my index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `successHandler` to in your authentication filter.

```
class JWTAuthenticationFilter
(private val authManager: AuthenticationManager, private var jwtUtil: JWTUtil) : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

    override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?): Authentication {
        try {
            val username = obtainUsername(request)
            val password = obtainPassword(request)
            val token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = token
            successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, token)

            return authManager.authenticate(token)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Original answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18507460/11392316)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should both allow "GET" and "POST" to your `/` url visit, so the quick fix is to change from `@GetMapping` to `@RequestMapping`

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    fun index(mode: Model): String{
        return "index"
    }
```